# run php script once in a week

Tags: php, cron

every Monday I need to empty few fields of a MYSQL database I have

Firstly I thought about using a cron job, but my Web Hosting provider (fatcow.com) doesn't support neither SSH or Command Lines into shared servers.

I've also thought about checking the date() to see if it's monday and perform something, but then I need to run that specific page continuously and I've read that it's a problem.

So now I ask you, how can I do this ?

Thanks for answers

Comment: Does Fat Cow (I love their slogan by the way, "Udderly Fantastic Web Hosting") support cron jobs?

Comment: yes I do but they don't support Cron Jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your job can reached via a URL, you might try to sign up with a free crontab service like onlinecronjobs.com

Comment: This is not a great answer, it does not help me at all or anybody looking to manually run a cron script.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to any other server that will allow to run cron job, you can create a php file there and run your url to be executed from that server. Use curl, wget or streams to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to any other servers that do allow cron, since FatCow doesn't, you could make a cron job that calls wget on a php script on your server -- eg wget http://example.com/fake-cron.php

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible to setup some kind of job in mysql itself. Not 100% sure about it, but read up on

```
CREATE EVENT something ON SCHEDULE
```

And maybe you find a way to do it from MySQL instead of PHP. Sorry I can't be of more help, just thought you'd might want to check it out

[MySQL Events](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

What's the control panel for that host?  cPanel?  If so, cPanel almost always has a Cron tool under Advanced.  Could also potentially do an [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) command from a php script to set up the Cronjob (unless that's what you mean by not supporting 'command lines').

Comment: exec/system command are likely to be disabled. cpanel definitely has cron facility, but many other panels are also likely to have it.

Comment: Never know until you try.  I don't think I've run up on a host where they were disabled, least not a paid host.  The user might not have permissions to set a cronjob though.

Comment: so I contacted them and they said that they don't have Cron Jobs support, have you got any ideas on a possible solution ?

Comment: Well, if the system doesn't support cron jobs as a whole, which is really weird, go with goreSplatter's answer about http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another server (with ssh) just add a cron job on it that hit your php script once a week.
Unfortunately i don't think there is a way to do it directly on your php script.