# How to execute PHP code periodically in an automatic way

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks

I am willing to truncate a table in a MySQL database periodically but I don't know how to make the code that does so run in a specific period of time automatically e.g every week. Do you know any approach or class to do so?

EDIT: I am on windows sever

Comment: Use a cron (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Cron is used in linux environments, right? Well, I'm on windows unfortunately...

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793051/php-mysql-once-a-week-operations  && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583930/run-php-script-once-in-a-week

Comment: http://www.onlinecronservices.com. The most popular services listed there are http://scheduler.codeeffects.com and http://www.crondroid.com/cron/daily

Answer (score 11):

You have two approaches.

First is based on **cron jobs** - your system may automatically call some PHP script every week. See more in [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [learn Cron based on examples](http://crontranslator.appspot.com/) (I have seen also some interesting tool somewhere on GitHub, but I am unable to find it at the moment).

The second is to call some task **during execution of different script**, eg. when you do not have access to `crontab`. You may eg. store information about executed scripts in the database - if 7 days have passed after last execution, then execute some function / script and save the new timestamp into the database.

**EDIT:**

You said you are on Windows, but there are cron-like solutions also.

To add scheduled tasks, follow the [guidelines from article on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/31506).

You can also run Cron-like software, eg. [CRONw - Cron for Windows](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: The URL for "learn Cron based on examples" http://crontranslator.appspot.com/ now shows: *"Python 2.5 is no longer available. Please refer to (URL that Stack won't let me paste) for more information."* - Can you update the answer in order to either remove it or to update it? Edit: You appear to be inactive.