# How to optimize a JOIN and AVG statement for a ratings table

Tags: mysql, left-join, average

I basically have two tables, a 'server' table and a 'server_ratings' table. I need to optimize the current query that I have (It works but it takes around 4 seconds). Is there any way I can do this better?

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(server_ratings.rating), 0), server.id, server.name
FROM server LEFT JOIN server_ratings ON server.id = server_ratings.server_id
GROUP BY server.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query looks ok, but **make sure you have proper indexes**:

- on `id` column in `server` table - probably primary key,
- on `server_id` column in `server_ratings` table,

If it does not help, then **add `rating` column into `server` table and calculate it on a constant basis** (see [this answer about Cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939667/how-to-execute-php-code-periodically-in-an-automatic-way/7939687#7939687)). This way you will save the time you spend on calculations. They can be made separately eg. every minute, but probably some less frequent calculations are enough (depending on how dynamic is your data).

Also make sure you query proper table - in the question you have mentioned `servers` table, but in the code there is reference to `server` table. Probably a typo :)

Comment: I'll look into Cron jobs, this is probably what I will need to do. I have all the indexes right, and yes it was a typo, fixed it :P

Answer (score 0):

This should be slightly faster, because the aggregate function is executed first, resulting in fewer JOIN operations.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, r.avg_rating
FROM   server s
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT server_id, ROUND(AVG(rating), 0) AS avg_rating
    FROM   server_ratings
    GROUP  BY server_id
    ) r ON r.server_id = s.id
```

But the **major point** are **matching indexes**. Primary keys are indexed automatically. Make sure you have one on `server_ratings.server_id`, too.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out how to fix the GROUP BY area, got a syntax error there. And yes I do have indexes there, I just recently learned their usefulness, thankyou.