# How do i load scripts with a specified times

Tags: php, autoload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute PHP code periodically in an automatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939667/how-to-execute-php-code-periodically-in-an-automatic-way)

I am trying to find a way in PHP to load specified script in a specified time, For example if the apache server can execute a specified script, Or mabye there is an option inside the php.ini so i can add files to load in a specified times.

**For example:**

I want to load the script **example.php** this file can be found inside the root directory at the location **X/Y/example.php**, What i want is that the **Php engine/Apache Server** will execute this script at 12:00, If anyone know a way doing so i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cron](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)

> Cron is a daemon that executes scheduled commands. Cron is started
>   automatically from /etc/init.d on entering multi-user runlevels. Cron
>   searches its spool area (/var/spool/cron/crontabs) for crontab files
>   (which are named after accounts in /etc/passwd); crontabs found are
>   loaded into memory. Note that crontabs in this directory should not be
>   accessed directly - the crontab command should be used to access and
>   update them.

For more info:
[croninfo.html](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)
[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 0):

[cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [GET](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_GET.htm) is all you need